# I need to recursively get the half of even integers in a list in python

Tags: python, recursion

I've gotten most of my code, but the only thing I'm struggling with is getting the odd numbers out of my created list. Here is my code:

```
def halfEven(x):
    if not x:
        return []
    else:
        i = x[0]
        if i % 2 == 0:
            i //= 2
        elif i % 2 == 1:
            x.remove(i)
    res = [i] + halfEven(x[1:])
    return res
```

While testing with `halfEven([0,5,2,99,555,6,2,4])` I get `[0,5,99,3,1,2]` but I want the answer `[0,1,3,1,2]`. Any nudges in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: well you're still returning [i] even when it's been removed from x. The only thing `x.remove(i)` does is remove it from the list that's getting passed to the recursive function. Which means that the *next* item gets skipped altogether, since it passes the list starting with 2 items later.

Comment: The only reason to use recursion would be to modify `x` in place, but since you are building a new list anyway, I would just use `return [y // 2 for y in x if y %2 == 0]` and be done.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I figured it out. I needed to create a list to store my halved evens, which in retrospect was the most obvious answer. Thank you for the nudges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by creating a list to store the answers. Here is the code:

```
def halfEven(x):
    if not x:
        return []
    else:
        i = x[0]
        evens = []
        if i % 2 == 0:
            i //= 2
            evens.append(i)
    res = evens + halfEven(x[1:])
    return res
```

Thank you for the help. I know it was an easy answer but I was struggling lol

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to create a list to store the answers -

```py
def halfEven(x):
  if not x:
    return []
  elif x[0] % 2 == 0:
    return [x[0] // 2, *halfEven(x[1:])]
  else:
    return halfEven(x[1:])
```

But really the consumer should be able to use the values as they are generated -

```py
def halfEven(iterable):
  for x in iterable:
    if x & 2 == 0:
      yield x // 2
```

If you want a more functional implementation, consider `itertools` -

```py
from itertools import filterfalse

def evens(iterable):
  return filterfalse(lambda x: x % 2, iterable)

def halfEven(iterable):
  return map(lambda x : x // 2, evens(iterable))
```

You can even use `operator` module for functional forms of `%` and `//` -

```py
from itertools import filterfalse
from operator import mod, floordiv

def evens(iterable):
  return filterfalse(lambda x: mod(x, 2), iterable)

def halfEven(iterable):
  return map(lambda x : floordiv(x, 2), evens(iterable))
```